# Can't figure out why this AutoIt code isn't working

Tags: autoit

the problem is that after you hit ok on this GUI, it doesn't start the function I have.

```
Func BeginningGUI()
   #Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=
   $Form1 = GUICreate("Stronghold Kingdoms", 248, 95, -1, -1)
   $Password = GUICtrlCreateInput("Password", 8, 32, 233, 21, BitOR($GUI_SS_DEFAULT_INPUT,$ES_PASSWORD))
   $ButtonOk = GUICtrlCreateButton("OK", 86, 64, 75, 25, $BS_NOTIFY)
   $ButtonCancel = GUICtrlCreateButton("Cancel", 167, 64, 75, 25, $BS_NOTIFY)
   $EnterPassLabel = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Please Enter Your Stronghold Kingdoms Password", 0, 12, 241, 17, 0)
   GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)
   #EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

   While 1
  $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
  Switch $nMsg
     Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        Exit
     Case $ButtonCancel
        Exit
     Case $ButtonOk
        Exit
        OpenSHK()
  EndSwitch
   WEnd
EndFunc
```

I want it to obtain the input word, then save that as a variable and enter it into the later function OpenSHK()

Also when I run OpenSHK() Alone it works fine so it's not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're exiting before the call to `OpenSHK()` is made, causing it to never be called.

```
   Case $ButtonOk
      Exit
      OpenSHK()
EndSwitch
```

Exit after that call is made instead:

```
   Case $ButtonOk
      OpenSHK()
      Exit
EndSwitch
```

The second problem is that `$Password` is not the password the user entered; it's a control ID. You need to use [`GuiCtrlRead`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/GUICtrlRead.htm) to retrieve the value the user entered after the `Ok` button has been clicked.

Comment: Thanks, but now whenever I try to run it after I hit Ok it isn't saving what I enter for $Password.

Comment: You should have made that clear in your question, which asks only about the function not being called. I've edited to include the other problem, but it really should have been a second, separate question instead. This site is designed for one question per post, so that a single answer can be provided. Multiple questions means that separate people can each answer one of them, making a correct answer difficult to determine. (I answer question #1, someone else answers question #2, and both answers are correct for their problem area. Which one is "correct" and can be accepted?)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info and sorry about that. I have posted another question about this project on a different page like you've suggested I do with any more questions.